# Automate setting environment variables for JBoss application

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, environment-variables

How can I have environment variables setup automatically from a file (eg. a properties or yaml file) when running a JBoss Java application?

Currently I do this through Eclipse’s Launch configurations for the JBoss server, but this way I can’t share the variables with other developers nor put them in version control.

Comment: How do you typically start WildFly?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins through Eclipse

Comment: I don't know if Eclipse uses the startup scripts. If it does you can setup the environment variables in the `standalone.conf` or `standalone.conf.bat` depending on your OS.